# Including a comment block in arquillian.xml causes errors

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I have the following arquillian.xml file used to specify the location of a Glassfish resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<container qualifier="glassfish-embedded" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="resourcesXml">
            src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>

<!-- <glassfish:container>
         <glassfish:instanceRoot>src/test/resources/glassfish</glassfish:instanceRoot>
         <glassfish:bindPort>9090</glassfish:bindPort>
         <glassfish:autoDelete>false</glassfish:autoDelete>
     </glassfish:container>-->
```

When I try and run a test, I get an error:

```
Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
```

I make a *single* change to the whole project which is to remove the comment block shown above and the test runs without errors.

What is the reason for this behavior? Is it a bug which should be reported?

Comment: I believe technically your XML is invalid.  Is this in fact the whole file?  Please also make sure to add the entire stack trace, as the exception has no cause listed.

Answer (score 0):

The "glassfish:container" namespace style of defining the configuration was dropped in Alpha4 or so, a few years back. The correct form is

```
<container qualifier="">
```

Comment: Agreed, and that is what I use in above the comments. But surely the contents of the comments should still be ignored?